# Trouble understanding how django-fluent-comments code works

Tags: django, django-comments

I've spent a bit of time digging around in django-fluent-comments recently.  I know a little bit of django, but am completely stumped by how this package works.

Essentially, I don't understand where the actual query to get the comments for an object is made.

In the function '[FluentCommentsList(node)](https://github.com/edoburu/django-fluent-comments/blob/master/fluent_comments/templatetags/fluent_comments_tags.py)', the queryset containing the comments appears to come from this call on line 67:

```
comment_list = context['comment_list']'
```

I've no idea where the actual query to populate 'comment_list' is made though.  It looks like the function [get_comments_for_model](https://github.com/edoburu/django-fluent-comments/blob/master/fluent_comments/models.py) in models.py might have something to do with this but I've tried to comment it out and the comments still appear on the page regardless.

Lastly, I don't understand how the foreign key relationship to user works.  In the database user_id on comments is a foreign key to the user model, but when I changed FluentCommentsList as so:

```
class FluentCommentsList(Node):
    def render(self, context):
        coms = context['comment_list']
        for c in coms:
            print c.user_id.user_picture
```

This results in the error below where it seems what should be a user model is interpreted as a long.

```
'long' object has no attribute 'user_picture'
```

Any chance someone could explain what's happening please?  All I'm really trying to do is access the user_picture field via the foreign key to user but it would also be really good to understand the code a bit better.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django-fluent-comments uses the default Django `Comment` model in `django.contrib.comments`. The `FluentCommentsList` you see is actually a template tag that recieves a context from the calling template - including a `comment_list` or `target_object_id` if you want the tag to work.

Each `Comment` includes a `ForeignKey` to a user. The reason you get an error is because you try to access a field on `user_id`, not on `user`. If your `User` model includes a `user_picture` field, the following should work:

```
coms = context['comment_list']
for c in coms:
    print c.user.user_picture
```

Comment: Ah ok, so a stupid mistake then.  Thanks a lot for pointing this out.  However, now I have this part working I still need to modify the original query which gets the comments so i can add a prefetch related and avoid triggering a lookup on each comment to get the profile picture.  Any idea where that happens, it looks like it has to be the query i pointed out but modifying it appears to change nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Got this figured out now, it gets it from comments app.  Thanks for the answer have accepted as it helped me a lot at the time..

Comment: How to remove <span> for comment-date and that? Means how to modify the way how comment is getting displayed after posting immediately.